# progressDialog wihile creating database

Tags: android, progressdialog

Could you help me to change piece of code to show progresDialog or some information during database creation. I have tried to do this with Thread with no success. When I put most of code to thread I get error, when only db.createDataBase() "text" is set before database is created.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  myCalendar = new MyCalendar();
  menu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poleMenu);
  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.glownePoleTekstowe);
  menu.setText(kalendarz.setCurrentDateOnView());
  value = menu.getText().toString();

  db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

  try {
    // separate class to load database
    // MOST IMPORTANT
    db.createDataBase();

  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("nie można utworzyć bazy danych");
  }


  dane = db.getDataFromDate(value);
  db.close();
  try {
    log = dane.getTekst();
  }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
  text.setText(log);
}
```

Update, with thread and handler:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  kalendarz = new Kalendarz();
  menu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poleMenu);
  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.glownePoleTekstowe);

  menu.setText(kalendarz.setCurrentDateOnView());
  value = menu.getText().toString();

  db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

  // thread
  ladujDane();

  dane = db.getDaneFromDate(value);
  db.close();
  try {
    log = dane.getTekst();
  }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
  text.setText(log);
}
```

//------------------------------------------

```
public void ladujDane() {

  mLoadDBHandler = new Handler()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
  };


  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
  this,
  "Ładowanie danych", "Proszę chwilkę poczekać", 
  true,
  false);

  Thread t = new Thread(new LoadDBThread());
  t.start();

}
```

//----------------------------------------

```
private class LoadDBThread implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {

    try {

    db.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("nie można utworzyć bazy danych");
    }

    mLoadDBHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Are you using AsyncTask in your not working code?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8 android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. /// I use Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to do UI operations on another thread than the main thread.

You could use a handler for that. First declare a handler:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // do UI stuff
        }
    };
```

Then from your thread that creates DB you call: `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

Comment: I did it yesterday. I've written code in onCreate() then there is a function that run thread(thread only creates database) and then the rest of code. It works without errors but "text" isn't set. I got empty TextView. I don't know well how it works but maybe thread is still working while "text" is set.

Comment: @Mirek did you use a handler yesterday? I don't get your response.

Comment: I read your post one again :) and moved text.setText... to handler and it works :). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Just use AsyncTask you can safetly mage progress bar from it's onProgress.
You can't change UI elements from thread other than UI thread, on the other hand you can't do long lasting operations in UI thread. AsyncTask is your answer.

Comment: I've tried to use AsyncTask last week but had some problems. E.g. with db = new DatabaseHandler(this); I don't know what should be instead of "this" to make it working.

Comment: @Mirek your context which is your activity you could pass it to the asynctask when you create it through the constructor.

Comment: AsyncTask is probably your inner class in the Activity. So "this" means AsyncTask, not MyActivity. If I'm right with your code construction (AT is inner class of MyActivity) try MyActivity.this

Comment: @piotrpo I will take your advice and try to do it with AsyncTask one again, but now it works with Thread, thanks

Comment: AsyncTask will do exactly what you have done with Thread. The only difference is you have not to write such a lot of code :) All that stuff you have encapsulated with AT class.